# Nonexistent line number in "Your script has recently failed to finish successfully"

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a google spreadsheet script which I run on a timed trigger, and have opted to receive notifications when it fails. If I run it manually it works fine, but when it triggers I receive the following notification:

> Start Function    Error Message   Trigger End 9/28/12 9:45
>   PM    plotPortfolioData   TypeError: Cannot call method "getSheetByName" of
>   null. (line 5)    time-based  9/28/12 9:45 PM

The problem is, line 5 is empty, and neither line 4 nor line 3 have any "getSheetByName" function

```
function plotPortfolioData() {

  // get the Portfolio Chart sheet, and create it if it doesn't exist
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  var portfolioDataSetT = transpose(GetComprehensivePortfolioData(ss));

  varSheetName = "Charts";

  // IMPORTANT
  var firstIndividualStockColumn = 6; // first column in portfolioDataSetT where the actual individual holdings start

  // loop through every value in the portfolio dataset and replace 0 with a blank string (this has the effect of removing
  // any 0 quantity lines from the stacked charts).
  for (var i = 2; i != portfolioDataSetT.length; i++) // start at i = 2 to skip the header and first row (needed for charting)
  {
    for (ii in portfolioDataSetT[i])
    {
      if (portfolioDataSetT[i][ii] <= 0)
      {
        portfolioDataSetT[i][ii] = '';
      }
    }
  }


  if (!ss.getSheetByName(varSheetName))
  {
    var newSheetCreated = true;
    ss.insertSheet(varSheetName);
    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(varSheetName);
  }
  else
  {
    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(varSheetName);

    // remove all charts in this existing sheet
    var charts = sheet.getCharts();
    for (var i in charts)
    {
      sheet.removeChart(charts[i]);
    }
    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(varSheetName);
  }

  // Build the data into the spreadsheet
  var sheetDataRange = sheet.getRange(1, 1, portfolioDataSetT.length, portfolioDataSetT[0].length);
  sheetDataRange.setValues(portfolioDataSetT);

  // prepare the pie chart data
  // start by listing the individual stock names vertically
  var number_of_custom_rows = 1; // the number of manual rows we will add that are not just stocks
  var pieChartSize = (portfolioDataSetT[0].length + 1 - firstIndividualStockColumn) + number_of_custom_rows; // number of holdings in the pie chart
  var pieChartFirstColumn = portfolioDataSetT[0].length+1; // just start after the data pile

  var pieChartStockTitles = sheet.getRange(1,1,1,portfolioDataSetT[0].length).getValues(); // the range of headers
  var pieChartHoldingsRange = sheet.getRange(portfolioDataSetT.length,1,1,portfolioDataSetT[0].length);
  var pieChartHoldings = pieChartHoldingsRange.getValues(); // range of holdings values

  // set the pie chart holdings range number format
  pieChartHoldingsRange.setNumberFormat("$#,###");

  var pieChartDataSpace = sheet.getRange(1,pieChartFirstColumn,pieChartSize,2); // the space where the pie chart data will be printed for graphing (2 columns for name and holding value for each stock)

  for (var i = 0; i != pieChartSize - number_of_custom_rows; i++)
  {
    pieChartDataSpace.getCell(i+1,1).setValue(pieChartStockTitles[0][firstIndividualStockColumn-1+i]); // add the name of the holding to the first pie chart column
    pieChartDataSpace.getCell(i+1,2).setValue(pieChartHoldings[0][firstIndividualStockColumn-1+i]); // add the value of the holding to the 2nd pie chart column
  }

  // now add the custom rows
  pieChartDataSpace.getCell(pieChartSize,1).setValue(pieChartStockTitles[0][4]); // add the cash header
  pieChartDataSpace.getCell(pieChartSize,2).setValue(pieChartHoldings[0][4]); // add the cash amount

  var chartHeight = 400;
  var chartWidth = 500;
  var offset = 3; // buffer region in pixels between charts and the edge of screen

  // hide the numbers for neatness:
  sheet.hideRows(1,portfolioDataSetT.length);

  // performance chart (top left)
  var performanceChart = sheet.newChart()
      .setOption('title', "Portfolio Measurements")
      .setPosition(portfolioDataSetT.length, 1, offset, offset)
      .setOption('height',chartHeight)
      .setOption('width',chartWidth)
      .setOption('lineWidth',1)
      //.setOption('vAxis.format',"$#,###")
      .setOption('vAxis.gridlines.count',10)
      .setOption('theme','maximized')
      .setChartType(Charts.ChartType.LINE)
      .addRange(sheet.getRange("A:D")) // date,cost base, cash-only,cost-base no cash
      .build();
  sheet.insertChart(performanceChart);

  // performance chart (bottom left)
  var compositionChart = sheet.newChart()
      .setChartType(Charts.ChartType.AREA)
      .setOption('title', "Portfolio Composition")
      .setPosition(portfolioDataSetT.length, 1, offset, 2*offset + chartHeight)
      .setOption('height',chartHeight)
      .setOption('width',chartWidth)
      .setOption('theme','maximized')
      .setOption('vAxis.gridlines.count',10)
      .setOption('isStacked',true)
      .setOption('lineWidth',0)
      .setOption('areaOpacity',0.8)
      //.setOption('vAxis.format',"$#,###")
      .addRange(sheet.getRange("A:A")) // dates
      .addRange(sheet.getRange("E:E")) // cash balance
      .addRange(sheet.getRange(1,firstIndividualStockColumn,portfolioDataSetT.length,portfolioDataSetT[0].length + 1 - firstIndividualStockColumn)) // add the individual stock holdings
      .build();
  sheet.insertChart(compositionChart);

  // pie chart portfolio composition (top right)
  var pieChart = sheet.newChart()
      .setChartType(Charts.ChartType.PIE)
      .setOption('title', "Portfolio Composition")
      .setPosition(portfolioDataSetT.length, 1, 2*offset + chartWidth, offset)
      .setOption('height',chartHeight)
      .setOption('width',chartWidth)
      .setOption('pieSliceText','label')
      .setOption('is3D',true)
      .addRange(sheet.getRange(1,pieChartFirstColumn,pieChartSize,1)) // add the individual stock names
      .addRange(sheet.getRange(1,pieChartFirstColumn+1,pieChartSize,1)) // add the individual holding values
      .build();
  sheet.insertChart(pieChart);

  // fix up number formatting
  var sheetWholeRange = sheet.getDataRange();
  sheetWholeRange.setNumberFormat("$#,###"); // set all numbers to currency
  var sheetDateRange = sheet.getRange("A:A");
  sheetDateRange.setNumberFormat("d-LLL-YYYY"); // set date column formatting
}
```

So, what's going on, how am I supposed to debug this problem? When I run it, it works fine!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems the problem is in the following line

> var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

When you start this script manually, I assume, you start if as a spreadsheet script from either the `Spreadsheet Script Editor` or the `Spreadsheet Script Manager`. In this case the `getActiveSpreadsheet` returns the active sheet which is opened now and `ss` is not `null` - everything is fine.

When you start the same script from a timed-trigger then there is no any active spreadsheet and the `getActiveSpreadsheet()` returns `null`. After that, probably, somewhere inside of the `GetComprehensivePortfolioData` method there is a line `ss.getSheetByName('...')`. In this line the exception is thrown.

I think, the `GetComprehensivePortfolioData` method is in a separate `gs` file and the first `getSheetByName` call is at the line 5.